# Need help creating a function that returns the size of the string you type in

Tags: c, c-strings

So the practice problem I'm doing asks to write a complete C program that inputs the line of text from the keyboard and calculates the size of the entered string. Your program should use a function stringLength()which calculates and returns the size of the given string. Function has the following prototype:size_t stringLength(const char* sPtr);

The following is what I have but I'm still learning the ropes as I'm going. I'm assuming it's asking to implement pointers as well and I'm very crusty when it comes to pointers. The function is basically where I'm stuck at, any tips or pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype
size_t stringLength(const char* sPtr) {

    int* str = &sPtr;
    return sizeof(str);
}

int main() {

char* s[100]; //input string

puts("Enter a string");
fgets(s, 99, stdin);

printf("According to stringLength, the length is: %d\n", stringLength(&s));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, a string is an array of characters with a 0 (known as the NUL terminator) at the end. So you need a loop to search for the 0.

Comment: With `fgets()` it is simply `fgets(s, 100, stdin);` NO `-1`, it will ensure the string is nul-terminated. You can also use `fgets (s, sizeof s, stdin);`

Comment: One other note. When using `fgets()` the trailing `'\n'` (as a result of pressing **Enter**) will be included at the end of the stored string. You usually want to trim that off by overwriting with the *nul-terminating* character. But note, to do so, you have to scan forward to the end of string anyway -- which gives you the length of the string (you don't want to do that twice). So consider have your function check for and remove the `'\n'` if present. (you actually don't need a function, you can simply do `size_t len; s[(len = strcspn(s, "\n"))] = 0;` immediately after your call to `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should use array of `char`, not array of `char*`, to store strings.
- `sizeof` is for determining size of types. You should use `strlen()` to determine length of strings.
- After fixing the type of `s`, Pass `s`, not `&s`, to `stringLength` to match the data type with the argument.
- `%d` is for printing `int`. You should use `%zu` to print `size_t`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// prototype
size_t stringLength(const char* sPtr) {

    return strlen(sPtr);
}

int main() {

    char s[100]; //input string

    puts("Enter a string");
    fgets(s, 99, stdin);

    printf("According to stringLength, the length is: %zu\n", stringLength(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally right,  but why not use `strlen` directly? Usually they are asked to implement the function using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: This is it, thank you. I learned about strlen literally a week ago, I must have forgotten what it actually does. Thanks again.